# Error in converting date-time to number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, file-io

I have a .csv file that contains two columns of time data. I want to convert it to a date number, but I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> datenum at 174
DATENUM failed.

Error in ==> Interpolasi_Suhu_dan_waktu_16_02_17 at 21
t = datenum(M{1});

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtvecmx
    The input cell array must be either a column or a row.
```

Here is the .csv file (Waktu_16_02_17.csv):

```
0:03:13 0:02:58
0:13:13 0:12:58
0:23:13 0:22:58
0:33:13 0:32:56
0:43:13 0:42:58
0:48:11 0:57:59
0:58:13 1:07:59
1:08:13 1:17:59
1:18:13 1:27:59
1:28:14 1:37:57
1:38:14 1:52:59
1:44:31 2:02:57
```

And the code I used is:

```
fid = fopen('Waktu_16_02_17.csv', 'r');
M = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', 1);
fclose(fid);

format short g
g = M{1};
```

Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Still I can't see correct formatting of your CSV file (is it `\n` after each string? is it 2 strings or just 1 long?). But your code works perfectly for me.

I just copied your data and create new .csv file. It contains 1 string.
So after using your code I get (using `whos` command):

```
Name      Size           Bytes  Class     Attributes

  M         1x1            718  cell
```

Next, lets see what is inside of `M`:

```
M{1}

ans =

  1×2 cell array

    '0:03:13 0:02:58 0:13:13 0:12:58 0:23:13 0:22:58 0:33:13 0:32:56 0:43:…'    ''
```

We can see that `M` has 2 cells. First one contains all string data from csv and second one just empty.
Ok, so lets put in `g` string from csv:

```
g = M{1}{1}
```

In your code you used `g = M{1}` but to take data we need to do one level deeper. Maybe you can use just `M{1}` if your csv has another formatting and textscan return resulting string in `M`.
Ok, now `g` is a char array that contains 191 char symbols: all the dates and spaces.

Now what is your problem - incorrect data type for `datenum` function. You can use `datenum` for cell arrays, but cell array must be a string of an column. Looks like your `M{1}` array is a table (2 strings and some columns).

In my case to use `datenum` for my `g` char array I have to go this way:

```
datenum(g(1:8))

ans =

    7.367e+05
```

This way is how to get correct `datenum` for the first date from your data. To get all of them just split array to the correct parts (use loops or `arrayfun` functions etc.).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here, one with your use of [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) and one with your use of [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html).

You call your file a .csv (short for "comma-separated values"), but it doesn't appear as though commas are used as separators based on the sample data you show. It appears to be separated by whitespace, which is the [default delimiter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#input_argument_d0e1008500) used by `textscan`, so I'd try this instead:

```
fid = fopen('Waktu_16_02_17.csv', 'r');
M = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'CollectOutput', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

Assuming the data is loaded properly, `M{1}` will contain an N-by-2 cell array. The `datenum` function has a limitation that its [`DateString` input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_DateString) can only be a 1-D cell array, while `M{1}` is a 2-D cell array. You can get around this by either using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) or reshaping the data [before](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [after](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) passing it to `datenum`:

```
t = cellfun(@datenum, M{1});
% Or...
t = reshape(datenum(M{1}(:)), size(M{1}));
```